# How to select element without selecting children elements

Tags: css, css-selectors

When I select an element, it selects **all** child elements. For Example

```css
div {
  border: solid;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p>
    Some Text
  </p>
  <div>
    <p>
      Some Text
    </p>
  </div>
  <p>
    Some Text
  </p>
</div>
```

It not only makes the **large** div's border solid, it also makes the **inner** div's border solid.

EDIT: is there a way to select the higher div without making a class?

Comment: It doesn't select "**all** child elements" -- notice it does not select the `<p>`s which are child elements. It selects all `div`s  in the DOM regardless of where they are in the hierarchy of the DOM tree. I recommend https://css-tricks.com/how-css-selectors-work/

Comment: assign a class to your div and refer to it

Comment: You could select only top-level divs ... select a div and style it _only_ if it is _directly_ a child of the page `<body>` element: `body > div { border: solid; }` -- but then if you have `<body>..<main>..<div> .. </div>` that _wouldn't_ be selected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are applying styles to all divs, for differences it creates a class

```css
.parent {
  border: solid black 1px;
}

.child {
  border: solid green 1px
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <p>
    Some Text
  </p>
  <div class="child">
    <p>
      Some Text
    </p>
  </div>
  <p>
    Some Text
  </p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

A CSS selector will apply its style to all matching elements. If your style uses `div` to match an element, the pertinent styles will be applied to all `div` elements within your HTML. (It won't apply to any of the `p` elements as they don't match). You need to find a way to be more specific when targeting an element.

One way might be to add a class to the div in your HTML. For example `div class="border-div"> ... </div>`. The element can now be targeted in your style-sheet using the selector `.border-div { ...`.

Another way might be to target the parent element with one selector and the children with another selector. For example you would target the parent div as you've already done: with the selector `div { ...`. But you can further target its children and override styles set to the parent with `div div {...`. Selectors that are more specific will always override selectors that are less specific.

For more reading on valid CSS selectors see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Selectors